# RAR file with alternate data streams

Tags: ntfs, rar

I have a RAR archive created under Windows and the NTFS file system, using alternate data streams feature of NTFS (RAR can archive those). What tools can I use to observe or extract alternate data streams from a RAR archive? Can I also add an alternate data stream to an existing RAR archive?